# Nodejs - file attributes and POSIX ACL

Tags: node.js, file, unix, filesystems, posix

Does Nodejs provide any more or less native way of checking file attributes and POSIX ACLs?

I mean those:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#chattr_and_lsattr (especially `nocow` and `immutable` bits)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

Second ones I believe are stored as extended file attributes and set/read via `getxattr`/`setxattr` on C level.

by native I mean without actually calling `setfacl`/`getfacl`/`chattr`/`lsattr` via child_process and parsing stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has no built-in way of calling `setxattr` / `getxattr`. But there are native addons you can use, e.g. https://github.com/LinusU/fs-xattr

```
npm install --save fs-xattr
```

```
const xattr = require('fs-xattr')
xattr.get("/path/to/file", "com.attr.name", (err, val) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`com.attr.name = ${val}`)
})
```